# Constructing NewsArticle objects from a database table

Tags: java, database, hash-map, constructor, type-safety

This class seems to be able to represent the data stored in any possible database table:

```java
public class DbTable {
    private Set<Map<String, Object>> tblData = new HashSet<Map<String, Object>>();

    public DbTable(Connection dbConn, String tblName) throws Exception {
        PreparedStatement prpStmt = dbConn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM " + tblName);
        ResultSet queryResults = prpStmt.executeQuery();
        ResultSetMetaData metaData = queryResults.getMetaData();

        while (queryResults.next()) {
            Map<String, Object> row = new HashMap<String, Object>();

            for (int i = 1; i <= metaData.getColumnCount(); i++) {
                String colName = metaData.getColumnName(i);
                String colClassName = metaData.getColumnClassName(i);
                Class colClass = Class.forName(colClassName);
                Object colValue = colClass.cast(queryResults.getObject(i));

                row.put(colName, colValue);
            }
            tblData.add(row);
        }
    }

    // ...
  }
```

Then, I'd like to construct objects to represent news articles based on the `Map<String, Object>` retrieved via `DbTable`, like this:

```java
public class NewsArticle {
    private final String Id, Title, Story;
    private final Timestamp Pubdate;

    public NewsArticle(Map<String, Object> row) {
        String id = null; String title = null; String story = null;
        Timestamp pubdate = null;

        for (Map.Entry<String, Object> col : row.entrySet()) {
            if (col.getKey().equals("id")) { 
                id = (String) col.getValue();
                continue;
            }
            if (col.getKey().equals("pubdate")) { 
                pubdate = (Timestamp) col.getValue();
                continue;
            }
            if (col.getKey().equals("title")) {
                title = (String) col.getValue();
                continue;
            }
            if (col.getKey().equals("story")) {
                story = (String) col.getValue();
            }
        }

        Id = id;
        Pubdate = pubdate;
        Title = title;
        Story = story;
    }

    // ...
}
```

So, a `Map` represents a database table entry as the column name, `mapEntry.getKey()`, and the data in the column, `mapEntry.getValue()`.

Because I lose type safety, I'm thinking this is rubbish. But, **(1)** users of `DbTable` most certainly should know the type of each column. **(2)** if they do not know the type, then they can use reflection as a backup way to make `DbTable` usable.

This solution seems to work fine. Any opinions about losing that type safety? How could I improve this?

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Is this your code ? You seems to want an explanation of how the code works. If this is what you are looking for know that this type of question is off-topic  for Code Review. Please read the [help] for more info.

Comment: @Marc-Andre I did write the code. As can be seen, I put 3 pieces of data into one map: "col-name", "object", and (by casting) I snuck in the object type (as would be viewable by reflection). So, I'm just thinking it is probably a bad solution because Java code should be strongly typed. And, I'm breaking that convention. But, it does work and I personally like how generic it is. So, what should I do... if it suits my needs, should I subvert Java's type safety?

Comment: @Marc-Andre Are classes similar to that in a textbook? I tried googling, but I can't find anything. Could I have asked the question in a different way?

Comment: Since it's your code and you just want a better way that preserve type-safety, your question is perfectly on-topic! I was just checking with you to make sure! I hope you have good review of your code! If you want type safety you can look into JPA.

Comment: @Marc-Andre You're almost surely correct about JPA. Why am I trying to solve problem that is so common that of course there is already a professionally done solution... my design just does not feel acceptable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Coding Issues

1. In `NewsArticle`, the names of the attributes begin with uppercase letters (`Id, Title, Story, Pubdate`). This violates common Java field naming conventions.
2. Database column names are usually case insensitive. Depending on the underlying DBMS, the instructions like `col.getKey().equals("id")` may fail, because the searched value could have been stored under e.g. `ID` key when being read in `DbTable`. Either it should be normalized by applying `toLowerCase()` there, or it should be checked with `equalsIgnoreCase()` in `NewsArticle` constructor.
3. Looping over the entire `row` map in `NewsArticle` constructor is unnecessary. The fields may be initialized with e.g. `id = (String) row.get("id");` and there is no need to use local variables `id`, `title` etc.
4. In `DbTable`: `Class colClass` var is not typed (raw type), which is not good. This variable is useless, because `colValue` is an `Object` and can be directly initialized with `queryResults.getObject(arg)`, without casting.

#### Design Issues: Critical!

There are some very important issues concerning `DbTable` class.

1. Loading the contents of an entire table using `tblData` Set is very dangerous. First of all, if the table is rather huge (imagine just several dozens of thousands of rows), this object will squatter the memory and probably consume too much of it uselessly. It also duplicates the data supposed to be stored in the DB and produces too much overhead on each `DbTable` object creation by reading all the data. However, reading just the metadata of table columns and their types could have been useful for your problem.
2. `prpStmt` and `queryResults` objects are created, but never closed. Initializing them inside a try-with-resources block will solve the issue.
3. `throws Exception`, especially in a constructor, looks very ugly. Either replace it with a more concrete exception type or (even better) find a way to avoid the `throws` clause for the constructor.
4. There are no validity checks for `Connection` and `String` arguments. What will happen, for example, if one of them or both are `null`?

These remarks do not answer your initial question about the type safety of the solution. It's too early to answer it before fixing many of the critical issues.

Comment: Now that's what I'm talking bout! I knew that was garbage, I just couldn't articulate why. thanks. I'll do better next time!